# Common table expressions (CTEs) with large tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, query-performance

Considering a query of the following format that uses CTEs:

```
WITH
    t1 AS (SELECT some_data1 FROM some_table),
    t2 AS (SELECT some_data2 FROM t1)
SELECT some_data3 FROM t2;
```

Question 1:

When the query is executed does a temporary table `t1` get built entirely and saved in memory, then `t2` is built entirely based on the data from `t1`, then the `SELECT` can run against `t2`?

Question 2:

If `t1` and `t2` are large tables that cannot be stored in memory will they be written to disk making the query slower?

Question 3:

Should this type of query be avoided for large tables?

Comment: I'd like to recommend [this awesome article](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/) from Craig Ringer to understand a bit more about CTE limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Answers:

1. Yes. Up to PostgreSQL v11, CTEs are materialized in PostgreSQL. This changes in v12, and from that version on your query will probably perform better.

   You can `EXPLAIN` the query to verify that.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.

Answer (score -3):

1. No. You can actually add more cte and not use them in the select at the bottom and they have no effect. The query optimizer turns them into the most efficient joins possible and executes it all together. For this reason CTEs are better and faster than temp tables.
2. This could be a problem with temp tables but no problem for CTEs. CTEs are just expressions representing the data a do not get called until the optimizer knows How you are selecting them.
3. Nope. In fact this is the way to go instead of tempt tables if your tables are large. Table size should not matter if you have proper indexes set up anyways. CTEs make it so you don’t have to process records that are just going to be filtered out later in the query anyways.